# requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" and targetSdk=30

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, scoped-storage

I am targeting SDK 30 and I am using Storage Access Framework and MediaStore API in my project.
All is working, but just for Android SDK 29 I need to use requestLegacyExternalStorage="true". This is because listing files (inside i.e. in the Music folder) is not permitted only in Android Q even if READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is set in the android manifest.

So my question is: on November 2021 does it still work when the app is run on Android Q?
If I understand well requestLegacyExternalStorage will be just ignored only on Android > Q and I do not use  MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#scoped-storage

Thanks for any help!

**Update:**
To be a bit more clear, what will be the behavior of requestLegacyExternalStorage=“true” targeting Android SDK 30 and running the app on 29?

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer? Because I've just hit the same issue. Do I need  android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" for my application to work on Android 10, even if i'am targeting SDK 30? Because I've tried the way from Android 11, but it doesn't work due to activity with setting not existing there.

Comment: sorry, no answer yet! My thought is that requestLegacyExternalStorage will just be ignored for SDK >= 30, at least I hope so